# Select DISTINCT parent_id

Tags: php, mysql

```
 //select parent_id - display unique value
<?php
//database connection
$con = mysql_connect("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("btreedata", $con);
//select distinct query
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM btree");
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
//dropdown list
echo "<select name='parent_id'>"; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo "<option value='".$row[0]."'>".$row[0]."</option>"; 
} 
echo "</select>"; 
?>
```

output show like this:

```
1000
1000
1004
1004
1003
1001
1005
1001
```

how can I display only

```
1000
1001
1003
1004
1005
```

Comment: This would not appear to be your actual code - as setting $sql isnt shown. Please show your full code  - also if you wanted your IDs sorted, you should add a sort condition.

Comment: I suspect your query is not that simple, otherwise it would return only the distinct values you expect. Although, you are using the query `$sql`...maybe you meant to use `$query`?

Comment: which type is "parent_id"? is this column defined as int or as (v)char?

Comment: If you run this directly on the database: SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM btree, what output do you get?

Comment: I HAVE TO DISPLAY DROPDOWN LIST LIKE:

Comment: you use $result = mysql_query($sql); ,but $sql is missing in code,check that variable ,that it contains correct sql statement or not.

Comment: You are running two queries: `$query  = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM btree");` and `$result = mysql_query($sql);`. And you even did not share `$sql` with your question.

Comment: Also please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250566/mysql-select-distinct - Your code should just work by the way, you're just a bit chaotic about it I'd assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  parent_id FROM btree group by parent_id order by parent_id ASC
```