# How to set limit for duplicate "items" returns within while loop?

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I use a while loop to echo member data to display each member's listing. I then use Jquery to filter the listings according to value(s) which are echoed from the `items` field. (i.e. the `items` field may contain "item1 item3 item10").This works well!!! Here's the code I have now.

```
<?php
$area = "Richmond";
$db_connect = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password","database");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno($db_connect)) { 
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
        }

$result = @mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT * FROM database WHERE territories LIKE '%$area%'");

    if (!$result){
        echo ("<p>Error performing listing query:" . mysql_error() . "</p>");
        }

$items = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    // Jquery uses these "$row["items"]" for it's filter
    $items[] = "<li class=\"services " . $row["items"] . "\">
    // more code here used to construct member's listing
    }
?>
//In the html, I echo each member's completed listing...
<?php echo $items[0]; echo $items[1]; echo $items[2]; etc... ?>
```

How can I set an echo limit to 12 duplicate value(s) from the `items` field? There are only 12 listings available for each value in `items`. So I want only the first 12 of each value to be included in the echo. If a member cancels, then `items` value(s) from next member will be echoed automatically. I hope this makes sense! :D

[EDIT] For more clarity, lets say 12 members list for "item1 item2" (both are in the `items` field). With the current code, the html for each listing would read `<li class="services item1 item2"></li>`.

Then a 13th member lists his services of "item1 item2 item3". Since "item1" and "item2"  exist 12 times, only item3 should echo. This new member's listing should read `<li class="services item3"></li>`. If a previous member cancels, all three items would be echoed.

I picture something like `if COUNT(items=%item1%) <= 12)` or something similar... I can't seem to wrap my mind around using `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` with my current set up.

Comment: refine your Query, try using DISTINCT http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250566/mysql-select-distinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. The first thing I had to do was create a different column for each item. Then it was a matter of counting each item from each row, allowing only the first twelve. I added the following:

```
$item1cnt = 0; //I added this section before the while loop to start the count at "0" for each item
$item2cnt = 0;
$item3cnt = 0;
$item4cnt = 0;
$item5cnt = 0;
$item6cnt = 0;
$item7cnt = 0;
$item8cnt = 0;
$item9cnt = 0;
$item10cnt = 0;
$item11cnt = 0;
$item12cnt = 0;

//And this inside the while loop to return only the first 12 of each item
if($row["item1"]!=""){ $item1cnt++; if($item1cnt > 12){$row["item1"]="";}}
if($row["item2"]!=""){ $item2cnt++; if($item2cnt > 12){$row["item2"]="";}}
if($row["item3"]!=""){ $item3cnt++; if($item3cnt > 12){$row["item3"]="";}}
if($row["item4"]!=""){ $item4cnt++; if($item4cnt > 12){$row["item4"]="";}}
if($row["item5"]!=""){ $item5cnt++; if($item5cnt > 12){$row["item5"]="";}}
if($row["item6"]!=""){ $item6cnt++; if($item6cnt > 12){$row["item6"]="";}}
if($row["item7"]!=""){ $item7cnt++; if($item7cnt > 12){$row["item7"]="";}}
if($row["item8"]!=""){ $item8cnt++; if($item8cnt > 12){$row["item8"]="";}}
if($row["item9"]!=""){ $item9cnt++; if($item9cnt > 12){$row["item9"]="";}}
if($row["item10"]!=""){ $item10cnt++; if($item10cnt > 12){$row["item10"]="";}}
if($row["item11"]!=""){ $item11cnt++; if($item11cnt > 12){$row["item11"]="";}}
if($row["item12"]!=""){ $item12cnt++; if($item12cnt > 12){$row["item12"]="";}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your database call, you can use GROUP BY and DISTINCT to only return one row for that value.  Also, if you were to add a check in the SELECT for whatever your cancellation flag is, that would remove all cancelled members from being pulled back anyways.  Something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Member WHERE IsActive = 'true' LIMIT 12
```

Without more information, this is the best I can come up with.

Comment: I edited my original post for clarity. Here is a test page to see a working example. [My Testpage](http://integritycontractingofva.com/asqlfile.php). Click the blue "Find a Professional" button to see the listings.