# How to prevent duplicates on a foreach loop inside another foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a music website where each time a user click on play, my PHP function insert into table `views`

I'm trying to reorder my MySQL database to optimize it in performance, so I tried in this example to count the total of views for each `track` grouped by time.

Select only tracks that are in table `views`:

```
$query = "SELECT  `track` FROM  `views` GROUP BY `track`";
```

The result for `$query`:

```
|track|
|-----|
|140  |
|125  |
|33   |
|...  |
```

Count the number of rows for each result as plays and group by date:

```
$querysel = $this->db->query(sprintf("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS plays , `time`, `track` FROM `views` WHERE `track` = '%s' GROUP BY DATE( `time` )", $tid));
```

The result for `$querysel`

```
|plays |time                |track |
|------|--------------------|------|
|82    |2016-12-26 18:20:16 |140   |
|1     |2017-01-10 15:52:55 |140   |
|2     |2017-01-26 13:17:25 |140   |
```

Final insert in a new table the result:

```
$this->db->query(sprintf("INSERT INTO views_counts (tid,plays,time) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')", $newtid, $plays, $time));
```

Here is my complete function:

```
function countViews() {

    $query = "SELECT  `track` FROM  `views` GROUP BY `track`";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $tid = $row['track'];

        $querysel = $this->db->query(sprintf("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS plays , `time`, `track` FROM `views` WHERE `track` = '%s' GROUP BY DATE( `time` )", $tid)); 

        while($rownew = $querysel->fetch_assoc()) {
            $rowsnew[] = $rownew;
        }

        foreach($rowsnew as $rownew) {

            $newtid = $rownew['track'];
            $plays = $rownew['plays'];
            $time = $rownew['time'];

            $this->db->query(sprintf("INSERT INTO views_counts (tid,plays,time) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')", $newtid, $plays, $time));

        }

    }

}
```

In my function I use `GROUP BY DATE(`time`)` ,so why the final query insert into the new table `views_counts` duplicates with the same time?

Here is my **output**:

```
id  | tid | plays | time
----|-----|-------|--------------
1   | 1   | 2     | 2017-01-26 12:43:16
2   | 1   | 1     | 2017-01-27 12:45:24
3   | 1   | 2     | 2017-01-26 12:43:16
4   | 1   | 1     | 2017-01-27 12:45:24
5   | 3   | 30    | 2016-12-26 18:20:16
6   | 1   | 2     | 2017-01-26 12:43:16
7   | 1   | 1     | 2017-01-27 12:45:24
8   | 1   | 2     | 2017-01-26 12:43:16
9   | 1   | 1     | 2017-01-27 12:45:24
10  | 3   | 30    | 2016-12-26 18:20:16
11  | 1   | 2     | 2017-01-26 12:43:16
12  | 1   | 1     | 2017-01-27 12:45:24
13  | 1   | 2     | 2017-01-26 12:43:16
14  | 1   | 1     | 2017-01-27 12:45:24
15  | 3   | 30    | 2016-12-26 18:20:16
```

As you see I have multiple same results for the same time.

Here is what I expected:

```
id  | tid | plays | time
----|-----|-------|--------------
1   | 1   | 2     | 2017-01-26 12:43:16
2   | 1   | 1     | 2017-01-27 12:45:24
3   | 3   | 30    | 2016-12-26 18:20:16
```

**UPDATE**

Here it is how I call this "one time" function:

```
<?php
    include("/var/www/html/includes/config.php");
    include("/var/www/html/includes/classes.php");
    session_start();
    $db = new mysqli($CONF['host'], $CONF['user'], $CONF['pass'], $CONF['name']);
    if ($db->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;
    }
    $db->set_charset("utf8");

    $feed = new feed();
    $feed->db = $db;                
    $result = $feed->countViews();

    mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

The function `countViews()` is inside `classes.php`.

I call this PHP just going to visit the requested page through the web.

Comment: @RiggsFolly as I said, this is only a one time function, I don't need to run the function every day...when I run the function the table `view_counts` is empty

Comment: Hey, if everything work what am I doing here.... bye

Comment: you have one row for each groupment. Maybe you don't show the millisecond of your time

Comment: FWIW, you can do this in one SQL query: `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM (SELECT ...)`.

Comment: Can you post the output of the inserted records.

Comment: An stored procedure maybe?

Comment: @bishop with only one `foreach` loop? Could you please show me your solution?

Comment: @Hackerman I need to run this only one time (for my old data), that's the reason why I don't use a procedure

Comment: post some sample rows of data please

Comment: Did you try using SELECT DISTINCT instead of SELECT? That's a good example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250566/mysql-select-distinct

Comment: and please post the sample rows and text. Also try to show expected output instead of what you got. Both as text please.

Comment: @Nicolaesse I already tried but it's not the solution, something is wrong with the double loop

Comment: You really don't need the second `foreach`. Just bring all the code out, replace `$rownew` with `$rowsnew` and that should be it.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena sorry I don't get it, I need to group by `track` and then by `time` ...could I see an example?

Comment: Would you mind adding a small sample data as SQL dump in either SQL Fiddle or Rextester to help simulate this? Thanks.

Comment: How are you calling countViews()? Is there a problem there?

Comment: Your `$rowsnew[]` is growing with each loop - reset it before second fetch or after insert loop. sql_dru's answer should work as well (if its *really* for one-time use).

Comment: With zero foreach loops, actually. The result is bijective on a subset of rows, so no loop is needed. Of course, I am sick right now, and this may just be fever talk.

Comment: @NineCattoRules countViews may be this function you call three time. can you make a simple page and call this function only one time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose to solve your issue using just one query.

```
function countViews() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS plays , `time`, `track` FROM `views` GROUP BY `track`,DATE( `time` );"); 
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $this->db->query(sprintf("INSERT INTO views_counts (tid,plays,time) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')", $row['track'], $row['plays'], $row['time']));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function countViews() {

    $query = "SELECT  `track` FROM  `views` GROUP BY `track`";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    $rowsnew = array();

    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $tid = $row['track'];

        $querysel = $this->db->query(sprintf("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS plays , `time`, `track` FROM `views` WHERE `track` = '%s' GROUP BY DATE( `time` )", $tid)); 

        while($rownew = $querysel->fetch_assoc()) {
            $rowsnew[] = $rownew;
        }

    }

    foreach($rowsnew as $rownew1) {

        $newtid = $rownew1['track'];
        $plays = $rownew1['plays'];
        $time = $rownew1['time'];

        $this->db->query(sprintf("INSERT INTO views_counts (tid,plays,time) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')", $newtid, $plays, $time));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't it be done *really* in a single query?

```
INSERT INTO views_counts (tid, time, plays)
    SELECT       track, DATE(`time`), COUNT(*)
        FROM `views`
        GROUP BY track, DATE(`time`)
```

Note that the rows to `INSERT` come from the `SELECT`.

I took the liberty of using `DATE(time)`, otherwise, *which* `time` is picked is arbitrary.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so only a single `SELECT` query should suffice, which will be as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT `track`, `time`, COUNT(*) AS `plays` FROM `views` 
                 GROUP BY `track`, DATE(`time`) 
                 ORDER BY `track`, DATE(`time`);"

$result = $this->db->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $newtid  =  $row['track'];
    $plays   =  $row['plays'];
    $time    =  $row['time'];

    $this->db->query(sprintf("INSERT INTO views_counts (tid,plays,time) 
                                     VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')", 
                                     $newtid, $plays, $time));

}
```

And that should ideally do the trick. A simple query demonstration using manually created sample data:

```
create table views (track int, `time` timestamp);
insert into views VALUES(1, '2017-01-26 12:43:16');
insert into views VALUES(1, '2017-01-27 12:45:24');
insert into views VALUES(1, '2017-01-27 12:50:30');

insert into views VALUES(2, '2017-01-25 01:00:00');
insert into views VALUES(2, '2017-01-25 02:00:00');
insert into views VALUES(2, '2017-01-26 11:30:00');
insert into views VALUES(2, '2017-01-26 11:45:00');
insert into views VALUES(2, '2017-01-26 13:45:00');
insert into views VALUES(2, '2017-01-26 15:45:00');
insert into views VALUES(2, '2017-01-27 08:00:00');

insert into views VALUES(3, '2017-01-27 09:00:00');


SELECT `track`, `time`, COUNT(*) AS plays FROM views 
GROUP BY `track`, DATE(`time`) ORDER BY `track`, DATE(`time`);
```

Output produced using this query, which is what is expected to land in `views_counts`:

```
track  |  time                |    plays   
----------------------------------------------
1      |  2017-01-26 12:43:16 |    1
1      |  2017-01-27 12:45:24 |    2
2      |  2017-01-25 01:00:00 |    2
2      |  2017-01-26 11:30:00 |    4
2      |  2017-01-27 08:00:00 |    1
3      |  2017-01-27 09:00:00 |    1
```

[Demo link](http://rextester.com/BGSE97061)

Hope that helps...