# Why is an item not getting selected in Dropdownlist OnRowDataBound event?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

In the `OnRowDataBoundevent` of the ASP.Net GridView I am trying to populate the Department DropDownList (ddlDepts) which will be displayed when a row is edited.

The code below is not working as the DropdownList is empty.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

'//GridView markup:

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department" ItemStyle-Width = "150">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID = "lblDept" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("deptName")%>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepts" runat="server" Visible = "false">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

''//Codefile

```
Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT(DeptID,DeptName) FROM Departments")
        Dim ddlDepts As DropDownList = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddlDepts"), DropDownList)
        ddlDepts.DataSource = Me.ExecuteQuery(cmd, "SELECT")
        ddlDepts.DataTextField = "DeptID"
        ddlDepts.DataValueField = "DeptName"
        ddlDepts.DataBind()
        Dim DeptName As ListItem = ddlDepts.Items.FindByValue("lblDept")
        If DeptName IsNot Nothing Then
            ddlDepts.SelectedValue = DeptName.Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you initializing a connection to the database that contains the departments table?

Comment: Possibly silly question, but are you certain your OnRowDataBound event is actually firing at all?

Comment: @inquisitive_mindm great question. I had it and started tinkering with the code and removed it in error. It is below:
            gvInPerson.DataSource = GetData(cmd) and connection to DB was defined in getData() sub. It did not help.
David W, no such thing as silly question but not sure why it would be firing though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which SQL you are using, but I think the query may be incorrect.

In MS SQL you would use it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DeptID, DeptName FROM Departments
```

And I have no knowledge of MySQL (or other databases), but a [quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250566/mysql-select-distinct) seems to indicate it uses the same methods for `distinct`.