# Mysql Why select count distinct return zero

Tags: mysql

I would like to know why select count distinct return zero result. I have also checked various answers at here but it's not answer for my case. MySQL version 5.6
Link to check
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/276302/3/0

**Sample schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `salary` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `employees` (`id`, `name`, `salary`) VALUES
  ('1', 'a', 6),
  ('2', 'b', 5),
  ('3', 'c', 5),
  ('4', 'd', 4);
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(salary))
FROM employees;
```

Guys, do you have any idea ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it [demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5e825761accbb2a68d4cb650131bb71e) Anyway I guess it has something to do with datatype VARCHAR(100). If you change it to INT it will work or add `'` [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35ab34/1/0). Probably some bug when sorting for DISTINCt

Comment: @lad2025 hm it's work when I change datatype INT but if I add `'` it will give incorrect value

Comment: **[Demo from MySQL 5.7](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5taBEKJ24TgMiYpoGYtYy2/1)** which works :) I suggest to upgrade.

Comment: @lad2025 it's seem ok on MySQL5.7. Do you think it's bug on MySQL 5.6 or something else what cause the incorrect result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250654/645132 I'm not sure if this might be why you're having an issue. Was trying to mess with your fiddle a bit to see if i could do it with a subquery, but I don't know MySQL as well as I do postgres

Comment: why are u inserting ints into a varchar datatype?

Comment: @lad2025 thanks you, actually I used MariaDB. I just make simple for testing purpose

Comment: @isaace Just a simple for testing. But event if I insert string it still make incorrect result

Comment: so please edit your question and fix it instead of misleading us. You already received 2 answers which are not relevant.

Comment: @isaace  Why I need to edit my question. What part make you misleading

Comment: that you are inserting int's into a varchar column. You can do what you want but people are confused as you can see of both answers.

Comment: @isaace I think it's not necessary, actually I think even string or int , it's must give the correct answer. You can check the demo was created by lad2025 above. It give correct result

Comment: @isaace Both answers just repharase my first comment. To sum up, it should work both INT/VARCHAR and so on. For MariaDB/MySQL 5.7/8.0 it is working so I guess it is a bug of version 5.6

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it is a bug of this specific version of [MySQL 5.6](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/276302/3/0).

But it will work for [MariaDB](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5e825761accbb2a68d4cb650131bb71e) or [MySQL 5.7](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5taBEKJ24TgMiYpoGYtYy2/1)

The other answers suggest that it is the problem with datatype.But if we remove `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(salary)
FROM employees;
-- 4
```

[DBFiddle Demo MySQL 5.6](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/276302/5)

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(ds) from (SELECT distinct(salary) as ds
FROM employees) as s;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the datatype of salary from varchar to int.
OR
you need to include salary values in " ".

Comment: because datatype is mismatched.

Comment: So please explain this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5taBEKJ24TgMiYpoGYtYy2/1

Answer (score 0):

This is [a known and long-standing bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30402#c392551) in MySQL. :-(

Answer (score -2):

Your salary column is type VARCHAR, try using INT or another appropriate data type.

See here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/875bde/1/0

Comment: It doesn't matter. Please check my demo for [MariaDB](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5e825761accbb2a68d4cb650131bb71e) Changing datatype is nasty workaround while it should work for strings too.

Comment: Sorry maybe im missing something, why MariaDB?

I don't think its a nasty workaround to suggest a different data type if possible. Creating queries which rely on correct formats added into a varchar column could create no end of issues.

Comment: Your answer suggests that COUNT(DISTINCT ...) should work only for INT which is not true. It is a clearly bug. Please check [MySQL Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5taBEKJ24TgMiYpoGYtYy2/1)