# How to add condition on virtual column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, having-clause

I want to add a condition for the  **tbl_restaurant_featured_history.id** column but I can't add that condition in where clause because It shows an error saying  **Unknown column 'featured'** in 'where clause' and If I add a condition  `featured is not null`  in having clause It is returning **0 rows**.

Below is the query before adding the condition

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT(tbl_restaurant.id) as restaurant_id,  
  tbl_restaurant.name,  
  tbl_restaurant_featured_history.id as featured, 
  tbl_restaurant.min_order_amount,  
  tbl_restaurant.latitude as latitude,  
  tbl_restaurant.logo, 
  tbl_favourite_restaurant.id as is_fav, 
  tbl_restaurant.address as address,  
  IF(tbl_restaurant_timing.start_time <= '19:56:26' && tbl_restaurant.service = 'Available' && tbl_restaurant_timing.end_time >= '19:56:26', 'Open', 'Closed') AS availblity,
  tbl_restaurant.longitude as longitude,  
  (
    SELECT ROUND(AVG(tbl_rate_review.rate)) 
    FROM tbl_rate_review 
    where tbl_rate_review.restaurant_id = tbl_restaurant.id 
    GROUP BY restaurant_id
  ) as avgrating, 
  (
    SELECT ROUND(AVG(tbl_rate_review.rate), 2) 
    FROM tbl_rate_review 
    where tbl_rate_review.restaurant_id = tbl_restaurant.id 
    GROUP BY restaurant_id
  ) as rating,  
  111.045 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(23.0266941)) * COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(longitude) - RADIANS(72.6008731)) + SIN(RADIANS(23.0266941)) * SIN(RADIANS(latitude)))) AS distance_in_km 
FROM tbl_restaurant 
LEFT JOIN tbl_restaurant_featured_history ON tbl_restaurant_featured_history.restaurant_id = tbl_restaurant.id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_restaurant_menu ON tbl_restaurant_menu.restaurant_id = tbl_restaurant.id AND tbl_restaurant_menu.status='Active' 
LEFT JOIN tbl_favourite_restaurant ON tbl_favourite_restaurant.restaurant_id=tbl_restaurant.id AND tbl_favourite_restaurant.user_id=19 
LEFT JOIN tbl_restaurant_timing ON tbl_restaurant_timing.restaurant_id = tbl_restaurant.id AND tbl_restaurant_timing.day = 'Saturday' 
WHERE tbl_restaurant.status = 'Active'  
HAVING distance_in_km <= 10  
ORDER BY availblity DESC, distance_in_km ASC LIMIT 10, 10
```

And the output of this query

[image]

Comment: Please make the effort to properly format your query. There is a button in the formatting bar to format text as code.

Comment: [DISTINCT is not a function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250654/20860)

Comment: Thank you so much @GMB ! is it looking formatted now?

Answer (score 1):

The query is poorly formated and hence rather hard to follow.

I can see this in the `select` clause:

```
tbl_restaurant_featured_history.id as featured
```

The `where` clause of a query just can't refer to an alias defined in the `select` clause. If you want to filter on this, then you need to use the column name (`tbl_restaurant_featured_history.id`) rather than the alias (`featured`):

```
where tbl_restaurant_featured_history.id is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

The table `tbl_restaurant_featured_history` is `LEFT` joined to the table `tbl_restaurant` and this is why you get nulls in the results because some rows do not match the conditions of the `ON` clause that you have set.
If you want to add the condition:

```
tbl_restaurant_featured_history.id is not null
```

this means that you want only the matching rows and from your sample data I see that there is only 1 matching row.
In this case all you have to do is change the join to an `INNER` join:

```
.................................
FROM tbl_restaurant 
INNER JOIN tbl_restaurant_featured_history ON tbl_restaurant_featured_history.restaurant_id = tbl_restaurant.id
.................................
```