# How to get the unique from two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table, I am trying to figure out a way to get the unique values from both the columns.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
col1 varchar(256) NOT NULL,
col2 varchar(256) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `test` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `test` MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

INSERT INTO `test` (`col1`,`col2`) VALUES ('A', 'B');
INSERT INTO `test` (`col1`,`col2`) VALUES ('A', 'C');
INSERT INTO `test` (`col1`,`col2`) VALUES ('A', 'D');
INSERT INTO `test` (`col1`,`col2`) VALUES ('B', 'D');
INSERT INTO `test` (`col1`,`col2`) VALUES ('B', 'E');
INSERT INTO `test` (`col1`,`col2`) VALUES ('C', 'F');
```

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Comment: The code looks like MySQL, so I removed the other database tags.

Comment: Can’t  help you with your homework but look into MySQL distinct keywork. Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250566/mysql-select-distinct#:~:text=DISTINCT%20is%20not%20a%20function,the%20columns%20of%20another%20row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `union`:

```
select col1
from test
union   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select col2
from test;
```

Comment: *from t;* - a typo.

Comment: This works: select col1 from test3 union select col2 from test3