# How to get DISTINCT of a SUBSTRING in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query,

```
SELECT t2.id, t1.image, SUBSTRING(t2.start_time,1,10) AS mytime, 
  t2.user 
FROM post_table t1 
INNER JOIN watchUserList t2 ON t1.id = t2.movie_id 
WHERE user = 'john@gmail.com' 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

In this query I want to fetch `DISTINCT` of `mytime`. I tried `DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(t2.start_time,1,10)) AS mytime` and `SUBSTRING(t2.start_time,1,10) AS DISTINCT(mytime)`. But both doesn't work. How to get Distinct of a Substring in MySQL. Is there any way?

Comment: Can you add some sample (input) data with desired output?   Because currently it's unclear if you do not know that DISTINCT if a modifier of the [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html), or that you are trying something different.

Comment: Why do you treat a datetime like a string? There are functions to get parts from a datetime, like `YEAR()`, `MONTH()`, `DAY()` or the date-part of a datetime via `DATE()`

Comment: [DISTINCT is not a function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250654/20860). It's a query modifier. You must write `DISTINCT` after the `SELECT` keyword, before all columns. The `DISTINCT` modifier applies to the whole row, not just one column.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t2.id, t1.image, SUBSTRING(t2.start_time,1,10) AS mytime, 
  t2.user 
FROM post_table t1 
INNER JOIN watchUserList t2 ON t1.id = t2.movie_id 
WHERE user = 'john@gmail.com' 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

But note, that its distinct over all the fields in the field-list.

> Distinct on Multiple Columns
> When we use MySQL Distinct on multiple columns, then the SELECT Statement writes the unique combination of multiple columns instead of unique individual records.

[Distinct On Multiple Columns](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/mysql-distinct/)

Comment: Did that work for you